# Stop infinite loop from EJB timer's timeout

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0

I am creating a timer like below using TimerService:

```
@Resource
private TimerService timerService = null;
...
Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(timeout * 1000, timerId);
```

Then performing an infinite loop during the timeout of the timer.

```
@Timeout
public void callTimeout(Timer timer){
    while(true){
        // do some process
    }
}
```

Is there any way using the Timer's option to ask the timer to stop the process of callTimeout()? I have tried the **timer.cancel()** but hopefully its not the right way to do this!

**Note:** I can not use the static variable to control the process as we do normally to control the threads.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: Creating a process through the timer that will usually run for a long time. Later I may wish to stop the process without waiting for it's completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Timer` for starting [async](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html) method:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
class MyEJB {
    @Resource
    private TimerService timerService = null;

    private Future<String> result;

    @EJB
    private Async asyncTask
    ...
    Timer timer = timerService.createTimer(timeout * 1000, timerId);

    @Timeout
    public void callTimeout(Timer timer){
        result = async.calculate();
    }
    public void cancel(){
        result.cancel();
    }
}

@Stateless
class Async {

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<String> calculate(){
        ...
        return new AsyncResult<String>(status);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a reasonable answer, but it's not quite enough: cancel requires a boolean, and I think it's worth pointing out that cancel(true) must be used, and then the calculate() method must periodically call SessionContext.wasCancelCalled.